# How do I fix Perl Getopt::Long event not found error?

Tags: regex, perl, getopt, getopt-long

I am using `Getpt::Long` to take the arguments from the command line and assign them to their respective variables. But, I am getting errors when I am printing it. The code and the error is as follows:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions(
    "mount_path=s" => \my $old_path,
    "var=s"        => \my $var,
    "log_path=s"   => \my $log_path,
) or die "Error in input variables\n";

print <<"END_INPUTS";
 These are your inputs: 
 old_path= $old_path 
 var = $var 
 log_path=$log_path 
 Press enter twice if all looks GOOD 
 *********************************************************
END_INPUTS
```

The command line arguments are as follows:

```
 perl getvar.pl --mount_path=/var/sslvpn --var=7.0.0.2_va-SSLVPN-!7.0.0.2.16sv+.jpn-05!j+g_554863- --log_path=log.txt
```

I am getting the following error while running this

```
-bash: !7: event not found
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a Perl problem.  The bash shell is processing `!` as a special character.  You'll have to quote that argument.

```
 --var='7.0.0.2_va-SSLVPN-!7.0.0.2.16sv+.jpn-05!j+g_554863-'
```

You can tell that it's a bash problem and not a Perl problem because the message says it's from bash:

```
-bash: !7: event not found
```

Bash never even gets to the part where it runs your program.